# How to get a sidebar taskbar?

Tags: unity, gnome, taskbar

In a lot of tutorials I see the very convenient side bar

[image]

I currently have the gnome desktop environment, and it has a completely empty desktop that requires me to click "Activities" in order to open a semi-task bar

[image]

Which for me is very annoying.

How do I get a task bar that stays?

I want my desktop to look like the above picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Askubuntu!

Have you tried to install dash-to-dock?

Edit: Glad this worked;

> Set the "dash to panel" to ON.

Screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: EDIT: Maybe you look for gnome-tweaks?   It has a lot of settings with windows/bars/panels ?  https://linuxhint.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/r19.png   Reply if this maybe wasn't what you wanted as answer

Comment: @Gulzar  Thank you so much;  it means alot.  I'm still new on these stack Ex sites but, thanks.  Have a great day!  Regards.  //Will.